# Insert into table cutting off first character (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

So I've got a bit of sql code that imports product descriptions from local HTML files. It works well for the most part, but for some reason removes the first character of line.

The query imports each file into a temporary table (#content1), which puts each line in its own row. A loop then runs to merge those rows into a single row in #content2. For some reason, when the data is merged into #content2 the first character of the first row is removed.

```sql
CREATE TABLE #files(filename VARCHAR(MAX))
CREATE TABLE #content1(content VARCHAR(MAX))
CREATE TABLE #content2(content VARCHAR(MAX))
CREATE TABLE #descriptions (
    SKU VARCHAR(255),
    Description VARCHAR(MAX)
)

--Get a list of all files in the eBay description folder
INSERT INTO #files 
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'dir /B "D:\eBay Descriptions\"'
DELETE FROM #files WHERE filename is NULL   -- removes null line from table

DECLARE @filename varchar(255)
DECLARE @command VARCHAR(255)

-- Loop until the #files table is empty (each time a line is processed it is deleted)
WHILE (SELECT count(*) FROM #files) > 0
BEGIN
    DECLARE @description varchar(MAX)

    SELECT TOP 1 @filename = filename FROM #files

    --Get file contents
    SET @command = 'type "D:\eBay Descriptions\'+@filename+'"'
    INSERT INTO #content1
    EXEC xp_cmdshell @command
    
    --Merges multiple rows into single row. THe above command puts each line from the type command into its own row so these need to be merged into one
    INSERT INTO #content2
    SELECT STUFF((
        SELECT content
        FROM #content1
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')


    SELECT TOP 1 @description = content FROM #content2
    
    --Inserts SKU and description into #descriptions table
    INSERT INTO #descriptions (SKU, Description) VALUES (REPLACE(@filename, '.html', ''), @description) 

    DELETE FROM #files WHERE filename = @filename   --Removes the processed file name from #files table

    select * from #content1
    select * from #content2

    --Empties the content tables so they can be used again
    DELETE FROM #content1
    DELETE FROM #content2
END
```

Example:
[image: example]

Can anyone see why this is happening?

Comment: You probably copy-pasted the `... FOR XML PATH('') ...` subquery from an example that concatenates columns with a delimiter like `,`. In such a construction you end up with an unwanted leading delimiter, which is often removed with the `STUFF()` function. You have no delimiter in your concatenation and therefore do not need the `STUFF()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because that's what you asked the statement to do, with the `STUFF` function:

```sql
SELECT STUFF((
        SELECT content
        FROM #content1
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
```

This *removes* 1 character after position 1 (so the first character) and replaces said character with `''` (aka no characters). It appears you don't need `STUFF` here.

If you're using a more recent version of SQL Server, you're better off using `STRING_AGG` though.

Comment: I cannot find any documentation of  `string_agg()` being deterministic without its `order by` clause. Because sorting on the HTML tags does not make sence, you might end up with the HTML content out of order.

Comment: @Sander A query without an `ORDER BY` clause will just put the rows in *any* arbitrary order; that's far worse. That is what you are doing in your `FOR XML PATH` query, meaning that the rows will be "aggregated" in any arbitrary order, and that could easily be different every time you run the query.